# How to read an Entry in Tkinter using a button in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-class

I am learning to work with classes in Python and I would like you to help me correct the following code, my goal is to make the button work and read what I put in the Entry:

```
from tkinter import *

class Ventana:

    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz= Tk()
        self.raiz.title('Central block')
        self.raiz.geometry('900x530')
        self.raiz.config(bg='black')
        self.label2= Label(text='Central Block',fg='blue',
                       bg='black',font=('Arial Black',18))
        self.label2.place(x=270,y=20)

    def accion():
        pass

        self.raiz.mainloop()


class Butt:
    def __init__(self,image,x,y,click):
        self.x= x
        self.y= y
        self.click= click
        
        Button(image=image,bg='black',relief='flat',
               borderwidth=0,activebackground='black',
               command= self.click, 
               cursor='hand2').place(x=self.x,y=self.y)

    def click():
        intro= Entry.get()
    
class Entries:
    def __init__(self,state,widt,x4,y4,textvar):
        self.state= state
        self.widt= widt
        self.x4= x4
        self.y4= y4
        self.textvar= textvar
        Entry(state=self.state,
              width=self.widt,
              textvariable=self.textvar).place(x=self.x4,
                                               y=self.y4)


ventana= Ventana()

entrada= StringVar()
texto= Entries('normal',7,70,365,entrada)

but8= PhotoImage(file='b2b.png')
boton8= Butt(but8,170,340,Butt.click)
```

The above produces the following error after writing something in the Entry and clicking on the button. I want to write something in the Entry and that when pressing the Python button it takes the value of that entry.:

```
>>>Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/X/test.py", line 32, in click
    intro= Entry.get()
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Use `entrada.get()` instead of `Entry.get()`

Comment: Puff !! Many thanks. I've spent hours trying to figure that out and it was silly. Please post the answer to rate yourself. Very grateful @TheLizzard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Entry` is a class not the object so when you call `Entry.get()`, it raises an error. Instead use `entrada.get()`.